# Spring WebMVC 5 - Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am following tutorials to configure spring security login for a Spring Web MVC project with Maven and Tomcat. I've read a number of questions asking about the same issue however none have provided a solution to my problem. The issue is with springSecurityFilterChain but I do not understand the what is involved in correcting the error.

The compilation error I get is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
```

My dependencies are:

```
  <properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
<spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
<tld.version>1.1.2</tld.version>
<servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
<jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
<spring-security.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
<spring.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.core.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
```

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-ldap -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
```

My security Config:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");

}

// Secure the endpoints with HTTP Basic authentication
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("login");
 }

}





import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {  HibernateConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebApplicationContextConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}


}
```

Comment: what is `${spring-security.version}` set to?

Comment: versions are set in the properties tag of xml dependencies list
<spring-security.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your version properties I see that you are using:

```
<spring-security.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
[…]
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

> Mind that the [DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.1.x/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui) was introduced in the `org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui` package starting with the `5.1.x` line.

So please take a look into your `mvn help:effective-pom` and align your `Spring Security` versions to the `5.1.x` line.

*Alternatively* you could give `Spring Boot` a try to make dependency management much easier.

Comment: You can use the Spring Framework bom to manage dependencies for Spring, no need for Spring Boot.

Comment: Of course you are right... but for me as a Spring Boot addict, the slight hint was a must. ;-)

Comment: I have updated the version however it was still throwing an error albiet a different error concerning the http.loginPage("login"); method which once I added a forward slash to e.g. http..loginPage("/login"); started to work